# C# Webbrowser Copy

Tags: c#, text, mouse, selection

I have a form that contains WebBrowser and context menu.

I want to disable the copy function in the context menu if user didn't select (highlight) any text in the page by mouse.

I tried to use

```
IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
if (range != null || range.text.Trim() != "")
    {
         MessageBox.Show(range.text);
         copyToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
         copyToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    }
```

but it didn't work for me.

[image: Error: Empty Selection]

[image: Selected Text Display Correctly]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this issue after debugging the application

Here it is if anyone needs it

The problem was range.text != "null" <- null here as string

```
private void contextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats()[0] == System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.StringFormat)
            {
                pasteToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pasteToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }

            IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = MainBrowser.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
            IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = htmlDocument.selection;
            if (currentSelection.type == "Text")
            {
                IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
                if (range.text != "null" || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(range.text.Trim()))
                {
                    copyToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    copyToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                copyToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```